# Set Wordpress Post Thumbnail from External image link using Python-xmlrpc

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordpress, python-2.7, wordpress-rest-api

After a lot of Google I landed up here: **How can I set a post Thumbnail using an external image link from an instead of attachment id?**.

Here is all that I can find, however I can't change it to set the thumbnail from an external image link.

```py
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import NewPost

#authenticate
wp_url = "https://blog.com/xmlrpc.php"
wp_username = "My_User_ID_on_WP"
wp_password = "My_PWD_on_WP"


wp = Client(wp_url, wp_username, wp_password)

#post and activate new post
post = WordPressPost()
post.title = '3 Post'
post.content = '<h1>heading 1</h1>Tayloe was here<br><small>here too!</small><p>New para.'
post.post_status = 'draft'
post.thumbnail = 50  # The ID of the image determined in Step 1
post.slug = "123abc"
post.terms_names = {
  'post_tag': ['MyTag'],
  'category': ['Category']
}
wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

**Note**: I don't want to save image on my servers and use an external image only

Comment: Is python xmlrpc an absolute dependency of yours, here? It's a modification that *could* be made, but you'd have to hook into WP core.

Comment: @CameronHurd No its not my absolute dependency but ya its a prefered method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try downloading the image, uploading it to your Wordpress site, and using the ID for the thumbnail parameter as you are above:

```
import base64
import requests

# ...

# raw string url
url = r'https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/20190530/ourmid/pngtree-cartoon-google-icon-download-image_1257171.jpg'

# retrieve and store base64 encoded image and mime-type
r = requests.get(url)
mime_type = r.headers['Content-Type']
img_base64 = base64.b64encode(r.content)

upload_image_dict = {
    'name': 'some_file_name.ext',
    'type': mime_type,
    'bits': img_base64,
    'overwrite': True
}

resp = wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.media.UploadFile(upload_image_dict)

image_id = resp['id']

# ... [ your code here]

post.thumbnail = image_id

# ...
```

https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/methods.html#wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.media.UploadFile

Comment: Next time you see plagiarism like that, feel free to use 'flag for moderator attention' to let us know.